# Error while running private docker image : standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I'm seeing

> standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format
>   error"

error while running my helloWorldC image as a container. What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

I tried the following steps on MacOS with Docker Desktop community edition.

Wrote a simple C++ program, compiled and created an executable.

```
$ cat helloWorldC.cc
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 cout << "###############################################################\n";
 cout << "\tHello from basic C++ HelloWorld Dockerized image \n ";
 cout << "###############################################################\n";
 return 0;
}
$

$ clang++ -o helloWorldC helloWorldC.cc

$ ./helloWorldC 
###############################################################
 Hello from basic C++ HelloWorld Dockerized image 
 ###############################################################
$
```

Then created a minimalistic Dockerfile for my 'helloWorldC' executable -

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM scratch
ADD helloWorldC /
CMD ["/helloWorldC"]
$
```

Built a docker image -

```
$ docker build --tag helloworldc .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 550.9kB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
---> 
Step 2/3 : ADD helloWorldC /
---> 35c21b2c67c9
Step 3/3 : CMD ["/helloWorldC"]
---> Running in bc22fbf4bf85
Removing intermediate container bc22fbf4bf85
---> 96e44669461a
Successfully built 96e44669461a
Successfully tagged helloworldc:latest
$
```

The Docker image is successfully created -

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE ID CREATED SIZE
.
.
helloworldc latest 96e44669461a About a minute ago 15.4kB
registry 2 f32a97de94e1 44 hours ago 25.8MB
.
.
$
```

While running the Docker container, I'm seeing following error.

```
$ docker run helloworldc
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
$
```

Following is my docker version -

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:33:12 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:41:49 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
$
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest an alternative solution which makes you able to compile your code and also keep the final image minimal as you wish. This can be done using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) which provided by docker. So your Dockerfile can be like this:

```
FROM gcc:5 as builder
COPY ./helloWorldC.cc /helloWorldC.cc
RUN g++ -o helloWorldC -static helloWorldC.cc && chmod +x helloWorldC

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /helloWorldC /helloWorldC
CMD ["/helloWorldC"]
```

Then after the build you will have a minimal image like this:

```
REPOSITORY      TAG    IMAGE ID     CREATED        SIZE
helloworldimage latest 89800885c997 22 seconds ago 2.17MB
```

And finally you can run it without any issues:

```
docker run --rm -it helloworldimage:latest
###############################################################
    Hello from basic C++ HelloWorld Dockerized image 
 ###############################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a dynamically-linked executable, and then tried to run it in a container without any of its libraries, or even the linker. A quick-fix is to call `clang++` with the `-static` flag, but note that glibc isn't really meant to be used that way, so you'll probably want to use musl or some other libc instead if this is more than a toy.

Also, you seem to be trying to compile a Linux binary on your Mac host. If you want that to work, you need to cross-compile. Alternatively, you can run `clang` on a Linux host, where it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to use '-static' flag, but that too didn't work. Got '-lcrt0.o' library error. 

$ clang++ -static -o helloWorldC helloWorldC.cc
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
$

Comment: @smulkutk Ah, I missed that you were on a Mac host. I edited info about that into my answer.